In VS Code, how to prevent the number of lines of file tabs from changing when switching between files?
Notice how in the first image, there is one line of filename tabs, while in the second image, there are two lines of filename tabs. The only change between image 1 and image 2 is clicking the right pane and then clicking the left pane.
How can I make it so that the number of lines stays the same when switching between files?
Here the right editor pane is in focus:

And here the left editor pane is in focus:

I have experimented with various settings, such as zoom and editor font style, but I haven't found the right setting to resolve this issue.
My best theory is that the font style changes when a tab is selected, which changes the width enough to start a new line. But I haven't found a setting that will keep the font style consistent regardless of whether the tab is selected.

I think this happens because of the little "Split Editor Right" button (the square icon with the line in the middle) appears when the left editor is selected and forces the tab onto a new line.
You can hide the split button by right clicking on it and selecting the option.  Then use the hotkeys to split the editor instead of the button.
